# Не получается прочитать текст из pdf файла

Tags: python, pdf

Используя следующий код:

```
import PyPDF2
pdf_file = open('1.pdf', 'rb')
read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
page = read_pdf.getPage(0)
page_content = page.extractText()

file = open("file.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
file.write(page_content)
file.close()
```

Пытаюсь прочитать текст из вот [этого](https://yadi.sk/i/dDpwnw5YxDoCOQ) pdf файла.

Но вместо текста получаю следующую ошибку:

```
PdfReadWarning: Xref table not zero-indexed. ID numbers for objects will be corrected. [pdf.py:1736]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 156, in <module>
    number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1155, in getNumPages
    self._flatten()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1505, in _flatten
    catalog = self.trailer["/Root"].getObject()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\generic.py", line 516, in __getitem__
    return dict.__getitem__(self, key).getObject()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\generic.py", line 178, in getObject
    return self.pdf.getObject(self).getObject()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1604, in getObject
    % (indirectReference.idnum, indirectReference.generation, idnum, generation))
PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError: Expected object ID (5 0) does not match actual (4 0); xref table not zero-indexed.
```

Что я сделал не так? Как можно исправить данную проблему?

Comment: Последняя строчка "PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError: Expected object ID (5 0) does not match actual (4 0); xref table not zero-indexed." говорит о том, модуль PyPDF2 не может работать с версией PDF выше 4-й. Тестовый пример - 5-я версия PDF.

Comment: @Assur Какую библиотеку посоветуете для комфортной работы с PDF 5 версии?

Comment: @СергейАндреев, похоже этот PDF состоит из единственной картинки. Чтобы получить содержимое в виде текста придётся данную картинку распознать при помощи какого-нибудь OCR софта или сервиса

Comment: Для распознания текстов пока лучше софта, чем ABBYY FineReader нет. К сожалению, распространяется данное ПО только платно.

Answer (score 1):

Протестировал доступные версии PyPDF. Это: PyPDF2, PyPDF3, PyPDF4.
Остался недоволен качеством выборки информации.

Тест проводился на PDF книге Алекса Мартелли "Python. Справочник. Полное описание языка [3-е изд.]",2019, изд-во "Диалектика". Объем PDF около 90 МегаБайт(881 страница). В текстовый файл выведено 397.9 КилоБайта(57431 строка!!!). Распознанию поддались цифры и латинские слова. Если кто-то данный модуль сделает для русского языка, то РуНет его не забудет))

Книгу не прилагаю,  а вот доработанный код выкладываю(размер списка page зависит от количества страниц в издании):

```
import PyPDF4
pdf_file = open('M.pdf', 'rb')
read_pdf = PyPDF4.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
page = []
for i in range(0,881):
    page.append('')

page_content = ''
for i in range(0,881):
    page[i] = read_pdf.getPage(i)
    page_content = page_content+page[i].extractText()

file = open("file.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
file.write(page_content)
file.close()
```

Comment: Используя ваш код, попытался достать текст из данного: https://yadi.sk/i/1YnU6mp7q93nmw файла. В итоге ничего не получил. Можете проверить?

Comment: Так пример, предложенный автором вопроса сделан именно под латиницу.
Я же упомянул, что выводятся знаки и латиница. Для случая с кириллицей еще не смотрел. Самому интересно.
С вашего файла test.pdf вывод есть - 8 байтов и все пробелы)). Файл то кириллический.

Comment: сейчас задал новый вопрос. Указал ваш код как исходный. Буду ждать. Возможно, кто-то найдёт решение

Comment: Перешерстил весь интернет по Питону.
Решение есть, но проект заброшен в 2012-м.
Подключают кириллицу в PyFPDF, но она не Unicode.
Т.е. обеспечены проблемы с перекодировкой на UTF-8.
Проект PyPDF4 живой был 143 дня назад. Там кириллицы нет.
Нет ее  и в  PyPDF2 из которого проект PyPDF4 вырос(PyPDF4 форк pyPDF2).